# Jhipster error deploying to heroku. Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource

Tags: heroku, jhipster

Im trying to deploy a jhipster app to heroku, its works fine when I run it in dev and prod profiles locally, but when I deploy it to heroku I keep getting this error.

```
2020-02-12T00:31:29.558205+00:00 app[web.1]: :: JHipster �  :: Running Spring Boot 2.1.9.RELEASE ::
2020-02-12T00:31:29.558207+00:00 app[web.1]: :: https://www.jhipster.tech ::
2020-02-12T00:31:29.558214+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-02-12T00:31:31.570261+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-12 00:31:31.566  INFO 4 --- [           main] c.aditum.cardiorehabcr.CardioRehabCrApp  : The following profiles are active: prod,heroku,no-liquibase
2020-02-12T00:31:36.173880+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-12 00:31:36.173  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2020-02-12T00:31:42.231677+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-12 00:31:42.230  WARN 4 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/target/cardio-rehab-cr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/aditum/cardiorehabcr/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7e46d648' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7e46d648': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2020-02-12T00:31:42.257589+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-12 00:31:42.251  WARN 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'liquibase': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361898+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-02-12 00:31:42.360 ERROR 4 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361900+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361902+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/target/cardio-rehab-cr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/aditum/cardiorehabcr/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7e46d648' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7e46d648': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361903+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361904+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361905+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361905+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361906+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361906+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361907+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.aditum.cardiorehabcr.CardioRehabCrApp.main(CardioRehabCrApp.java:65)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361907+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361908+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361908+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361909+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361909+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361910+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361910+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361911+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361918+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/target/cardio-rehab-cr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/aditum/cardiorehabcr/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7e46d648' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7e46d648': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361919+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:254)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361919+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.createDeploymentManager(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:287)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361920+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:213)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361920+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361921+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:153)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361921+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 14 common frames omitted
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361926+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/target/cardio-rehab-cr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/aditum/cardiorehabcr/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7e46d648' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7e46d648': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361926+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361927+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361927+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361928+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361928+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361928+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361929+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361929+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361930+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361930+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361931+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:211)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361931+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.getOrderedBeansOfType(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:202)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361932+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.addServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:96)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361932+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletContextInitializerBeans.<init>(ServletContextInitializerBeans.java:85)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361935+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getServletContextInitializerBeans(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:253)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361936+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.selfInitialize(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:227)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361936+00:00 app[web.1]: at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServerFactory$Initializer.onStartup(UndertowServletWebServerFactory.java:614)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361937+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:204)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361937+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:186)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361938+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361938+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361938+00:00 app[web.1]: at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:252)
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361939+00:00 app[web.1]: ... 18 common frames omitted
2020-02-12T00:31:42.361940+00:00 app[web.1]: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'auditEventsEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/audit/AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'auditEventsEndpoint' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customAuditEventRepository' defined in URL [jar:file:/app/target/cardio-rehab-cr-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/aditum/cardiorehabcr/repository/CustomAuditEventRepository.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'persistenceAuditEventRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#7e46d648' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#7e46d648': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space...
```

Here it is the entity map relationships created with  [1](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sergiocr16/CardioRehabCR/528014adaa0615c52efae3ff6368f2de1311468b/pom.xml): https://www.jhipster.tech//jdl-studio/

```
entity AppUser {
  name String,
  lastName String,
  authorityType Integer required,
  status Integer
}
entity Comorbiditie {
  description String required,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity ComorbiditiesPatient {
  description String,
  exist Boolean required,
  comorbiditieRelation Long
}
entity DepressiveSymptom {
  description String required,
  code String,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity DepressiveSymptomsSession {
  description String,
  exist Boolean required,
  depressiveSymptomRelation Long
}
entity FinalAssessment {
  smoking String,
  weight String,
  size String,
  iMC String,
  hbiac String,
  baselineFunctionalCapacity String,
  lDL String,
  hDL String,
  cardiovascularRisk String,
  isWorking Boolean,
  deceased Boolean,
  abandonment Boolean,
  abandonmentMedicCause Boolean,
  hospitalized Boolean,
  deleted Boolean,
  reevaluation Boolean,
  executionDate ZonedDateTime
}
entity IncomeDiagnosis {
  description String required,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity IncomeDiagnosisPatient {
  description String,
  exist Boolean required,
  incomeDiagnosisRelation Long
}
entity InitialAssessment {
  smoking String required,
  weight String required,
  size String required,
  iMC String required,
  hbiac String,
  baselineFunctionalCapacity String,
  lDL String,
  hDL String,
  cardiovascularRisk String,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity MayorEvent {
  description String required,
  code String,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity MayorEventsSession {
  description String,
  exist Boolean required,
  mayorEventRelation Long
}
entity MinorEvent {
  description String required,
  code String,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity MinorEventsSession {
  description String,
  exist Boolean required,
  minorEventRelation Long
}
entity NonSpecificPain {
  description String required,
  code String,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity NonSpecificPainsSession {
  description String,
  exist Boolean required,
  nonSpecificPainsSessionRelation Long
}
entity Patient {
  code String required,
  age Integer required,
  sex String required,
  ocupation String required,
  lastEventOcurred Integer required,
  deceased Boolean,
  abandonment Boolean,
  abandonmentMedicCause Boolean,
  rehabStatus Integer,
  sessionNumber Integer,
  deleted Boolean,
  scholarship String
}
entity RehabilitationCenter {
  name String required,
  telephone String,
  deleted Boolean,
  status Integer
}
entity RehabilitationGroup {
  name String required,
  creationDate Instant,
  programStatus Integer,
  deleted Boolean
}
entity Session {
  code String required,
  executionDate Instant required,
  abscence Boolean,
  hospitalization Boolean,
  status Integer,
  deleted Boolean,
  currentlyWorking Boolean
}
relationship OneToMany {
  RehabilitationCenter{appUser} to AppUser{rehabilitationCenter},
  RehabilitationCenter{comorbiditie} to Comorbiditie{rehabilitationCenter},
  InitialAssessment{comorbiditiesPatient} to ComorbiditiesPatient{initialAssessment},
  RehabilitationCenter{depressiveSymptom} to DepressiveSymptom{rehabilitationCenter},
  Session{depressiveSymptomsSession} to DepressiveSymptomsSession{session},
  Patient{finalAssessment} to FinalAssessment{patient},
  RehabilitationCenter{incomeDiagnosis} to IncomeDiagnosis{rehabilitationCenter},
  InitialAssessment{incomeDiagnosisPatient} to IncomeDiagnosisPatient{initialAssessment},
  Patient{initialAssessment} to InitialAssessment{patient},
  RehabilitationCenter{mayorEvent} to MayorEvent{rehabilitationCenter},
  Session{mayorEventsSession} to MayorEventsSession{session},
  RehabilitationCenter{minorEvent} to MinorEvent{rehabilitationCenter},
  Session{minorEventsSession} to MinorEventsSession{session},
  RehabilitationCenter{nonSpecificPain} to NonSpecificPain{rehabilitationCenter},
  Session{nonSpecificPainsSession} to NonSpecificPainsSession{session},
  RehabilitationCenter{rehabilitationGroup} to RehabilitationGroup{rehabilitationCenter},
  Patient{session} to Session{patient}
}
relationship ManyToOne {
  AppUser{user(login)} to User
}
relationship ManyToMany {
  RehabilitationGroup{patient} to Patient{rehabilitationGroup}
}

dto AppUser, Comorbiditie, ComorbiditiesPatient, DepressiveSymptom, DepressiveSymptomsSession, FinalAssessment, IncomeDiagnosis, IncomeDiagnosisPatient, InitialAssessment, MayorEvent, MayorEventsSession, MinorEvent, MinorEventsSession, NonSpecificPain, NonSpecificPainsSession, Patient, RehabilitationCenter, RehabilitationGroup, Session with mapstruct
paginate AppUser, Comorbiditie, ComorbiditiesPatient, DepressiveSymptom, DepressiveSymptomsSession, FinalAssessment, IncomeDiagnosis, IncomeDiagnosisPatient, InitialAssessment, MayorEvent, MayorEventsSession, MinorEvent, MinorEventsSession, NonSpecificPain, NonSpecificPainsSession, Patient, RehabilitationCenter, RehabilitationGroup, Session with infinite-scroll
service AppUser, Comorbiditie, ComorbiditiesPatient, DepressiveSymptom, DepressiveSymptomsSession, FinalAssessment, IncomeDiagnosis, IncomeDiagnosisPatient, InitialAssessment, MayorEvent, MayorEventsSession, MinorEvent, MinorEventsSession, NonSpecificPain, NonSpecificPainsSession, Patient, RehabilitationCenter, RehabilitationGroup, Session with serviceImpl
```

Once I create the entities via the .jh created with JDL-Studio and deploy it to heroku, sometimes I get the error sometimes I don't.

Here it is my pom.xml

[Pom.xml](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Sergiocr16/CardioRehabCR/528014adaa0615c52efae3ff6368f2de1311468b/pom.xml)

The application was generated using JHipster 6.4.1

Comment: Did you see that you got a "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"?

Comment: Thanks, yes I did , I upgraded my dyno type in heroku in order to give it more memory and also changed my Procfile, but it´s still crashing, so it appears that's not the issue. Or is it something else I can do to increase the heap space?

Comment: Have you contacted Heroku's support?

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with it? I thought it may be something else.